# Rayleigh test, getting only one answer from function (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have been trying to generate graph that looks like

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def rayleightest(t, f):
    pi = np.pi
    n = 528
    z = (1.0/n)*((np.sum(np.cos(2.0*pi*f*t)))**2+(np.sum(np.sin(2.0*pi*f*t)))**2)
    return z

def main():
    file = 'Rayleighdata.dat'

    t0 = np.loadtxt(file, usecols=(0,))
    t = np.array(t0)

    Pmax = 90
    Pmin = 1.5
    fmin = 1/Pmax
    fmax = 1/Pmin
    t1 = 1.08
    tn = 359.393
    T = tn - t1
    f0 = 1/T
    OFAC = 2.245
    fstep = f0/OFAC
    M = int((fmax-fmin)/fstep)
    j = 2348
    fj = fmin + j*fstep

    fk = np.arange(fmin, fmax, fstep)
    f = np.array(fk)


    list1 = list(map(rayleightest,t,f))

    x = np.linspace(fmin, fmax, fstep)

    plt.plot(x, list1, marker='o', linestyle='--', label='data')


    plt.legend()
    plt.show()




if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Now if I print list1, I got full list of only one number. Why is that? Before that I got float64 error if I use sum instead of np.sum.
I just don't know how to call that rayleightest function and iterate through all numbers (n=528) from file with every frequency.

If I just call

```
z = rayleightest(t, f)
```

I only got first answer with `t1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main()` function contains `list1 = list(map(rayleightest,t,f))`. This is how you get one answer per pair of values in `t` and `f` and got a bunch of values as a result. In other words the code computes `rayleightest(t[0], f[0])`, then `rayleightest(t[1], f[1])`, and so on.

When you use the code `z = rayleightest(t, f)` you pass 2 numpy arrays instead of 2 numbers. The result is a single value because the formula in `rayleightest()` contains `np.sum()` - you sum up all the values in arrays in a single value.

So the formula is the reason why you get single value for different input data. It is up to you to answer the question if this is expected behavior of the calculation process.

Now to the question why you get the same values in the list in the first case. Because for every pair of numbers you basically compute `sin(x * y) ** 2 + cos(x * y) ** 2` which is always `1` so `z` in `rayleightest` equals to just `1 / n`.

**EDIT**

Now when you have provided the original formula you try to implement with the code it became more clear what the problem actually is.

Modifications I've made:

(1) `list1 = [rayleightest(t, val) for val in f]`

(2) `x = np.arange(fmin, fmax, fstep)`

(3) `plt.plot(x, list1, 'r-', label='data')`

Result I get:

[image]

Comment: Now that makes sense, thank you. I'm still wondering how can I construct this [link](https://imgur.com/jUsiCrF) formula to get that graph. If I set manually `f = 1/2.85` (fbest) I get the value 12.6 which seems to be right when you look at the graph. Therefore I know frequency should be the x-axis. I just can't get it to iterate through all frequencies... I probably don't understand this problem at all, sorry.

Comment: I think I got the right answers just by adding `for i in f: z = rayleightest(t, i)` and deleting `list1 = list(map(rayleightest,t,f))`. Still getting dimension error when trying to plot...

Comment: @Tehp Check the EDIT addition.